# Remove unused imports with ast package?

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

After parsing a file and removing some functions, is it possible to also remove any now-unused imports before writing the new file?

Comment: `ast.File` has a field `Imports` – that's what you're looking for most probably.

Comment: Yes, I can edit them. However, if I've removed functions I don't know which imports are no longer used unless I walk through all of the code. Just wondering if Go has this functionality or if I have to build it.

Comment: I thought AST required the code to be compileable, and code with unused imports is not. I could be wrong there. The existing tooling for removing unused imports does not use AST: https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/cmd/goimports/goimports.go

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a need for something similar when writing a code generator tool.  Here's an outline of my solution:

- `golang.org/x/tools/imports` exports a func `Process` that will take a Go source file (as `[]byte`), and automatically "fixes" imports: remove unused imports and add unlisted imports that are referenced in the source file.  The `goimports` command is based on this.
- After editing my AST (e.g. removing some functions), I first print the AST to a Go source file string with `go/format`.  Note that this does not write to a disk file; it produces the string form of the AST in memory.
- Next I use `imports.Process` to "fix" the imports of the file.  It is important to pass the true file path of the Go source file to `Process`, even if it does not exist on disk yet.  The result of this call is a "fixed" Go source file as a `[]byte` "string"; i.e. any unused imports are removed.
- Now I perform a "diff" of the imports from the original AST and this "fixed" source file.  To perform the diff, it is easier to do so by comparing ASTs, so I first use `go/parser` on the "fixed" source file using `parser.ParseFile`.  I use the true file path of the Go source file, and an empty `token.NewFileSet()` when calling `ParseFile`.  Again, the Go source file does not have to exist on disk.
- The AST diff simply compares the `[]*ast.ImportSpec` slice (field `ast.File.Imports`) between each of the two file-root AST nodes.  (My implementation uses a `map` to index each `[]*ast.ImportSpec` first, making it easier to cross-check without a double-nested loop.)
- Finally, now that I have a list of `*ast.ImportSpec` that have been removed (unused), I use `golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil` to rewrite the original AST, using the cursor to remove these known `*ast.ImportSpec` nodes when visited.

An aside: the `imports` package cited above [has an "internal" package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/internal/imports#FixImports) that will provide a `FixImports` function that essentially provides the raw "diff" derived manually above.  Unfortunately we can't use it because it is marked as internal.